# ARRAYFORMULA that will show an image based on a true/false value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Looking for a formula that will display a specific image based on if a value is true or false.

sheet1 has a list of names.

In sheet 2 there is a list of names in 1 column, a row of options next to each name.  In this example, 10 options and 10 names.  Each column has a checkbox in the rows beside the names.  If the box is checked under one of the options, I want the image above those columns to display next to that name on a different sheet.  Hard to explain, will make more sense if you look at the linked sheet.

In way over my head with this one, but solving this would make my life a lot easier.
[example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PyxsnCwLjww6-cA0fvC0CdEdJDP4YWaOgTG0hPrnNMY/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: idurw's answer worked perfectly for my needs. https://stackoverflow.com/a/68916291/16745659

Comment: If that answer worked for you, I recommend marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noted that `A3` is filled with `Color`

***`MATCH` (non-ARRAYFORMULA):***

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!B$3:K$3,1,MATCH(TRUE,Sheet2!B4:K4,0))
```

***ARRAYFORMULA:***

```
=ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP("Color",Sheet2!A3:K3,VLOOKUP(G6:G15,QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN({Sheet2!A4:A13&"♦"&COLUMN(Sheet2!B3:K3)&"♦"&Sheet2!B4:K13}),"♦"),"select * where Col3=true",0),2,FALSE),FALSE))
```

Comment: this is PERFECT!  VLOOKUP is one of the one things im still very new with, thank you so much!